# How do I remove the ticks on the right side of a plot with Frame->True?

Tags: plotting

Consider the following code. I don't want the ticks on the right side. The ticks notation must remain in scientific form.

```
Plot [Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}, GridLines -> None, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick},FrameLabel -> 
{Style["x", FontSlant -> Italic], "Exp(x)"},FrameTicksStyle -> 
{Directive[Black, 19], Directive[Black, 19]}, 
LabelStyle -> {Bold, Directive[Black, 22]}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times"}, Frame -> True, 
PlotRange -> All, 
FrameTicks -> {Automatic, 
Table[{i, ScientificForm@i}, {i, 0., 25000, 5000}]}]
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

One possible way is to use replace your ticks options used with  this

```
Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}, GridLines -> None, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSlant -> Italic], "Exp(x)"}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {Directive[Black, 19], Directive[Black, 19]}, 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, Directive[Black, 22]}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times"}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All,
 FrameTicks -> {{Table[{i, ScientificForm@i}, {i, 0., 25000, 5000}], 
    None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Reference  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html.en

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you actually want the ticks but not the tick labels on the top and right side

```
Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, FontSlant -> Italic] & /@
    {"x", "Exp(x)"}),
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 19],
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 22},
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times"},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> All,
 FrameTicks -> {
   {Table[{i, ScientificForm@i}, {i, 0., 25000, 5000}],
    Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]